# How can we update documents transactionally in couchbase?

Tags: couchbase, transactional, distributed-transactions, couchbase-java-api

I have a use case in which there are three documents and I want to update them transactionally i.e. if any of them fails then other too should not get updated in the database. I was looking for an option but didn't find one in JavaSDK. So is there any way in which I can perform this operation transactionally. I am using the CAS value for handling the concurrency. Please provide me a way to handle this operation concurrently.

Couchbase Version: 4.0 
Java SDK: 2.1.6

Any help is appreciated.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Couchbase is a NoSQL database, where there is a tradeoff between ACID properties of traditional RDBMS and performance and scalability.

The only atomicity that couchbase can enforce is at the level of a single document.

There could be writings around the web on how to implement a transaction system with Couchbase, but that is clearly not something supported off-the-shelf, by design. It is a very complicated endeavour that I wouldn't recommend.

Try to model your documents differently first, so that the mutation can occur on a single document (where CAS could then be used).

Answer (score 0):

this doc (from couchbase) seems relevant:
[Providing transactional logic](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dev-guide-3.0/transactional-logic.html)

Comment: Yeah it seems correct but with this I do have a serious issue in mind same as this guy.
https://forums.couchbase.com/t/question-about-two-phase-commit/4424

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase now supports full ACID distribution transactions in the beta release of Couchbase Server 6.5.  Please see this [blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-brings-distributed-multi-document-acid-transactions-to-nosql/) for more details and links to the documentation.